# Is asking questions about a particular data set on-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-scope

Is asking questions about a particular data set on-topic on this Stack Exchange?

E.g. 3 questions pertaining to the [MIMIC data set](https://mimic.physionet.org/):

- [What is the exact date when data started to get recorded in MIMIC-II?](https://github.com/mimic2/v3.0/issues/98)
- [Are the APACHE scores available somewhere?](https://github.com/mimic2/v3.0/issues/56)
- [Why are there ICUSTAY_IDs that have no HADM_ID?](https://github.com/mimic2/v3.0/issues/68)

I am aware of [Is asking about how to use a particular data set appropriate?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/108/1652) but the question there is different: it asked whether asking the question "What possible uses are there for data set X?" is on-topic.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why it should not be on-topic?

Comment: @PatrickHoefler I don't see "asking questions about a particular data set" listed in http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @PatrickHoefler Otherwise I am totally fine if it's on-topic here, I was just asking as some folks behind MIMIC were looking curious if it was on-topic here. If not on-topic here then it may make sense to create an SE dedicated to data set specific questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any reason why discussing specific open data sets should be off-topic on Open Data SE. If nobody objects, we can also include a statement to that effect at [opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

**Update:** I just amended our on-topic help page.